# How to authenticate to both AzureRM and AzureAD with a single username/password prompt using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have several scripts that need to connect to both AAD and ARM, so I used this code snippet:

`$creds= Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds`

(I actually wrap the snippet with `Get-AzureRmSubscription` and only prompt for credentials if that fails).

But my organisation has implemented MFA, and I know I can't use the `-Credential` parameter anymore. So my connection snippet is now:

`Connect-AzureRmAccount
Connect-AzureAD`

(Still wrapped in the test condition).

However, the thing I've been trying to solve is **Can I somehow use the authentication 'token' from the first `connect` cmdlet and pass it to the second `connect` cmdlet?**

As workarounds, I could

1. Use a Service Principal to run my scripts
2. Use an account without MFA and go back to storing my credentials in a PSCredential object

But I don't think that will get passed the Security team who enabled MFA in the first place! :)

It's only a problem for new PS sessions. Once I have authenticated, the connection test passes and I don't get prompted again, but it just feels like it should be possible to only have to enter my username, password, and MFA challenge once. After all, I only have to login once to the Azure portal and get access to both AAD and ARM.

Comment: There is no cmdlet `Connect-AzureRmAccount`, it seems you want to use `Login-AzureRmAccount`

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT - I beg to differ: get-command Connect-AzureRmAccount |ft -a commandtype,name,version

CommandType Name                   Version
----------- ----                   -------
     Cmdlet Connect-AzureRmAccount 4.3.0 `login-azurermaccount` is an alias.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, on your scenario, I suggest you could use service principal to login Azure AD powershell and Azure RM powershell.

Comment: You need give this sp read/write your AD permission and your subscription owner role, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of the AzureRM module (v5.3.0) contains new cmdlets `*-AzureRmAd*` that appear to do the same thing as the `*-AzureAd*` cmdlets.

Therefore I need to update my scripts to use those new cmdlets. Then I don't need to connect to AAD, just need to connect once to ARM.

Comment: Would be nice if the `*-AzureRmAd*` cmdlets took the same parameters as the `*-AzureAd*` cmdlets.

Comment: Sadly not all functionality is ported to this :(

Answer (score 2):

According to your scenario, I suggest you could create a service principal to login Azure Power Shell and Azure AD Power Shell.

You could check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Connect-AzureAD?view=azureadps-2.0).

```
# Create the self signed cert
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate  = $currentDate.AddYears(1)
$notAfter  = $endDate.AddYears(1)
$pwd  = "<password>"
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName com.foo.bar -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $notAfter).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath c:\temp\examplecert.pfx -Password $pwd

# Load the certificate
$cert  = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("C:\temp\examplecert.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())


# Create the Azure Active Directory Application
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "test123" -IdentifierUris "https://test123"
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "Test123" -StartDate $currentDate -EndDate $endDate -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue

# Create the Service Principal and connect it to the Application
$sp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $application.AppId

# Give the Service Principal Reader access to the current tenant (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole)
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId 5997d714-c3b5-4d5b-9973-ec2f38fd49d5 -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId

# Get Tenant Detail
$tenant = Get-AzureADTenantDetail
# Now you can login to Azure PowerShell with your Service Principal and Certificate
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenant.ObjectId -ApplicationId  $sp.AppId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb
```

If you want to use this service principal to login Azure Rm Power Shell, you also need give it `Owner` or `Contributor` role. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#create-service-principal-with-self-signed-certificate)

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $sp.ApplicationId
```

Then you could login Azure Rm powershell using following command.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -TenantId $TenantId
```

Comment: `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId 5997d714-c3b5-4d5b-9973-ec2f38fd49d5 -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId` This is only read your AD permission, if you need more larger permission, you need modify the objectid. It is just an example.

Comment: Certificates won't be approved by Security just like the other options I thought of - they want the MFA challenge for admin tasks. I'm looking for a way to be challenged once and get access to AAD and ARM.

Comment: In fact, this is not possible. Azure AD powershell and Azure Rm powershell are different system. You need to log in separately. Of course, you could use same user/sp.

Comment: @Rincey_nz But you use MFA for you Azure AD user, it is not possible to use non-interactive login. Could you create a user not enable MFA?

Comment: You aren't really understanding my issue (except for your "AAD and ARM are different systems" comment). I'm happy to be challenged for MFA once, but just not twice. Now, if it can't be done, then that's fine, but maybe MSFT might like to think about this :)

Comment: Hmm, the two modules use `prompt=login` so that it always triggers interactive login. If the second didn't do that, it might actually just skip the auth as you already have an active session at that point.